# Implement simple back navigation with angular router

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I would like to implement a back button inside my header: It will move back from child to parent route!

Suppose I have the following nested routes: **/ => /bar => /bar/foo**

Now if I add a 'Go-Back' button inside my Foo component I can simply do

```
 this.router.navigate([".."], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
```

However, in my case the back-button is in the header (AppComponent) meaning that the above code doesn't work, I guess that ActivatedRoute points to **/**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-zdxivz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

So, my question is, how can I navigate back (child to parent) without ActivatedRoute?

UPDATE: I'm still working on this solution, I have the feeling that it should work (but right now isn't):

```
 const activatedRoute = this.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
 this.router.navigate(['..'], { relativeTo: activatedRoute });
```

[Stacblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ptshbv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: you can simply use `window.history.back()`. not sure if there are any downsides to that approach

Comment: No that will not work ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-nmtmtn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)) because of reload of bookmarking the url. Here is the [url](https://angular-router-basic-example-nmtmtn.stackblitz.io/bar/foo) and try the top-most back button

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try the `Location` service

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Location } from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <button (click)="goBack()">Go Back</button><br />
      <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/bar">Bar</a>

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private location: Location) {}

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought that this one was not working as well, but this is indeed the solution ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ptshbv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)). You also need to provide a little bit more than just **Location** ([link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-location-service))

Comment: Does this.location.back() works in jasmine test with Router?

Comment: Beware that there's an edge case with this scenario such that if user opens a new tab there won't be an entry in the history to go back to. This can throw user out of the Angular application as well as introduce security issues as there's no API for directly inspecting the browser history.

Comment: This method is not working in paramter based url.

Comment: @AliCelebi there is issue with Location is it reload holl previous route.

Answer (score 4):

use the global window api: `window.history.back();`